# Why can Java method parameters be explicitly covariant?

Tags: java, generics, covariance

In Java, you can use the `extends` keyword to declare that a given type parameter is covariant. Covariance and contravariance do confuse me a bit, but I think I've gotten a general sense of them. However, in my tests, it seems that Java type parameters are *inherently* covariant. So why can we explicitly state it?

For example, I built a quick sample that looks like this:

```
public class Main<E> {

    protected E value;

    public Main(E value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public <T extends E> void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public E getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main<Number> example = new Main<Number>(0L);
        System.out.println(example.getValue().getClass().getCanonicalName());
        example.setValue(32.0);
        System.out.println(example.getValue().getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }
}
```

The type used is Number, the superclass of all the boxed types. In the constructor, it takes a parameter which is declared of type E (in this case Number). In the `setValue` method, on the other hand, it takes a parameter which is declared to be anything *extending* type E. Both println calls return the proper value (first `java.lang.Long`, then `java.lang.Double`).

The way I see it, removing generics, you can still pass subclasses. If the class was declared with no type parameters and the methods/constructor took/returned Numbers, it'd still work properly.

So what is the purpose of the `extends` keyword in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, there is no benefit to using `extends` in `setValue`. You're right that the `T` declared by `setValue` could be replaced by its upper bound, `E`:

```
public void setValue(E value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

But consider this instead:

```
public <T extends E> T setValueAndGiveItBack(T value) {
    this.value = value;
    return value;
}
```

That means we can do this:

```
Double d = example.setValueAndGiveItBack(32.0);
```

Without `T`, the most specific type `example.setValueAndGiveItBack` could return would be `Number`.

Just to clarify, you're also right that type parameters are inherently covariant. The reason for using `extends` is to restrict a type parameter's upper bound. For example, `<T>` is implicitly `<T extends Object>`. In the above example, without declaring `E` as `T`'s upper bound, we wouldn't be able to assign `value` to `this.value` since it could be any `Object`.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks! I was trying to write a system that actually used values similarly to this, the base class was generic and held a value of type "E", which subclasses then expanded on. Not really understanding this, I went ahead and used <T extends E> for basically all my methods thinking I needed to for something like a `setValue()`. Now I see I really don't. That should help clean up my code a lot, thank you!